# Como funciona o "ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem"?

Tags: c#, threadpool

Já fiz algumas pesquisas a respeito mas não estou conseguindo achar uma explicação mais didática, tendo em vista que não possuo nenhuma experiência com threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thead Pool:**

Fornece um pool de threads que podem ser usados para executar tarefas, postar os itens de trabalho, processar E/S assíncrona, aguardar em nome de outros threads e processar temporizadores.

**Utilização:**

Você deve utilizar das threads quando deseja que a thread principal do seu sistema não fique travada aguardando a execução de uma tarefa que pode ser demorada.

**UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem:**

Ao contrário do método `QueueUserWorkItem`, `UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem` não propaga a pilha de chamadas para o thread de trabalho. Isso permite que o código perca a pilha de chamadas e, portanto, eleve seus privilégios de segurança.

**Observações:**

Usar `UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem` poderia abrir inadvertidamente uma brecha de segurança. A segurança de acesso ao código baseia suas verificações de permissão nas permissões de todos os chamadores na pilha. Quando o trabalho é enfileirado em um thread do pool de threads usando `UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem`, a pilha do thread do pool de threads não terá o contexto dos chamadores reais. Código mal-intencionado pode ser capaz de explorar isso para evitar verificações de permissão.

**Referencia:** [UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.unsafequeueuserworkitem?view=netframework-4.8) [ThreadPool](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=netframework-4.8)